# ReactJS fetching API - having CORS error

Tags: reactjs, cors, fetch

Sending request from ReactJS app:

```
fetch(http://my-api-domain, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors', //tried no-cors and same-origin
        headers: {
            'X-Auth-Token': auth_token' // custom-header
        }
    }).then(response => console.log(response))
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

`package.json` file has `"proxy": "http://my-api-domain/"`

Then I'm having this error on browser (firefox):

```
- Cross-Origin Request Blocked: (Reason: missing token ‘x-auth-token’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).
- Cross-Origin Request Blocked: (Reason: missing token ‘access-control-allow-headers’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).
- Cross-Origin Request Blocked: (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

PS: API server configuration is fine. I've tested my API on Postman. Send GET request with header `key: X-Auth-Token; value: [token]`. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This works in postman because it ignores CORS requests.

If you set 'no-cors' mode, it can still be ignored by the browser, as a security measure. Chrome will most certainly ignore this flag and return you an error.

Solutions:

- Whitelist your IP on the api, if it's your api
- Set up a reverse proxy such as Nginx that will add allow origin header for you. You will then do a request to a RP, and it will return the response with Allow-Origin header attached for you
- Set up a .php or node.js proxy endpoint locally, which will do the same as a RP
- Start your browser in no security mode.

**Chrome -no security (Windows) example**

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --disable-web-security
```

Comment: i have found the solution. I should've proxy my back-end :)